# Allow JSON Input for Parameter, but do not Serialize in Output

Tags: .net, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, annotations

I need to have a .NET Web API that will allow input from a JSON object for a field, but will not serialize it out. I have tried the [JsonIgnore] annotation, but that ignores it entirely, including input, for any json object.

Model

```
public class MyModel{
    [Key]
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Byte[] file {get; set;}
}
```

Json Input

```
{
    "name" : "MyName",
    "image" : "akjsfjkha37842hui23yh23b"
}
```

Desired Output

```
{
    "name" : "MyName"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you should use a ShouldSerialize[field] method. Json.NET determines whether to serialize a field into JSON by looking for a method. Using the below will prevent 'image' from serializing:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeimage(){
return false;
}
```

This should be placed in the model.